# Can I set the location of a page, without actually refreshing/reloading it?

Tags: jquery, window.location

**Question:**

Can I set the location of a page, without actually refreshing/reloading it?

**Problem:**

My problem is the page is loaded via a get variable page.html?userid=12345.

The key is one of the fields editable on the page, and the submit is using jQuery .post, so the page address never changes.

However, if they press refresh at this point, the url is pointing to a non-existent userid.

I want to set the location to userid=12345, but *without* actually retreiving that URL (cause I want to retain my jQuery modified page).

This seems like a security/phishing risk, so I suspect this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not having the best browser support and the domain will match, use [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: Domain will match, but I need to support IE6. Found this though - http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/?state=2 which supposedly gives IE6 support. Will check it out tomorrow.